# Creating a url redirect similar to .tk?

Tags: html, url

I used to host my site using .tk for my free wordpress website and notice that even though they are only redirecting it the url still works normal. It will show something like mywebsite.tk/signup/

Is there a way for using a html or php to redirext website in a similar way?
I'm thinking of iframe but they doesn't seem to correspondent your url in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a "reverse proxy", which transparently connects a client to another website. These are usually used in distributed computing, but can be made to work for simple name-hiding too.

As for a PHP specific solution, there seems to be a library for that: https://code.google.com/p/php5rp/

But since you're using PHP, you probably have access to a underlying Apache. If you do, take a look [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html), a Apache module that comes preinstalled in most servers.

If you have package installation rights in your server (e.g. you have a VPN), I would recommend [Nginx](http://nginx.org/) to setup a reverse proxy. It's a very versatile tool.

Comment: After some reading this seems to be the right answer but I still can't get my head on using it. Should I use mod_rewrite or mod_proxy? Will I get twice the bandwith for every request for it, mysite.example.com go through mysite.com and client?

Comment: @Nameless `mod_proxy` is the way to go if you're able to install Apache modules, but to use `mod_rewrite` as a reverse proxy, see the "Reverse Dynamic Mirror" section of the `mod_rewrite` docs. About the bandwidth, yes, it will duplicate the amount of bandwidth your server consumes, since it will act as bot a client (for the source) and a server (for the user-client). I personally never used Apache as a reverse proxy, so you might want to ask a new, more specialized follow-up question here if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are redirect mechanisms available in PHP and HTML both. Here it goes

- For PHP, use `header`. More information can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).
- For HTML, use `meta refresh`. More information can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76.html).

Comment: Can you show me which one that works on hiding the real address? I tried some of them to redirect and instead of using my url it shows the new url.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain your original domain name (.tk or other) then you can use PHP to "include" the page you are after, rather than redirecting the user to somewhere else.

Try this:

```
<?php include 'example.php'; ?>
```

That will simply grab the contents of example.php and put it in the current page. It won't replace the entire page, though, will just include it.

Comment: I tried it and it does not work. Are you sure it can work with url?

Comment: What code are you using for it? Forgot to mention that you have to enter in a file path rather than a URL.

Comment: I'm using it to redirect my site to a free service blog like wordpress or blogspot. Basically I want to have a mysite.com have all the content of mysite.wordpress.com without using iframe, or plain redirect, I need it to show something like mysite.com/signup

Comment: In that case... I'm pretty sure blogspot and wordpress.com allow you to use your own custom domain? That way there will be no redirections of any sort. Have you considered this? Seems like the best thing to resolve your question.

Comment: Wordpress required you to pay for having a domain mapping service and in my hosting case I cannot access the dns configuration to change it for my new hosting name.